# How to run selenium test in parallel while WebDriver and required fields are Protected in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I am not an expert in Java and learning things. Let me first let you know that I am using Selenium with Java using page object model and TestNg. Until now all the 1000+ tests run smoothly. As I am using all the following fields in my `baseTestClass` as

```
public static WebDriver driver;
protected static WebDriverWait wait;
protected static WebDriverWait longWait;
public static BasePage basePage;
public static AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness;
public static String tenantName;
public static String userRole;
public static String testType;
public static String browserName;
```

Now my senior suggested me not use `static` fields but instead use `protected`, because I am going to use the TestNg parallel option to reduce the test suite time.

Until now i modify the base class as follows

```
public class BaseTestClass {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseSeleniumTest.class);
protected String browserName;
protected String tenantName;
protected String userRole;
protected String testType;
protected AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness;
protected WebDriver driver;
protected WebDriverWait wait; //Explicit Wait
protected WebDriverWait longWait;
protected BasePage basePage;

@Parameters({"profile", "browserName", "userRole", "testType", "areaOfBusiness", "tenantName"})
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup(@Optional("local") String profile, @Optional("chrome") String browserName,
                  @Optional String userRole, @Optional String testType,
                  @Optional("BMW") AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness, @Optional("Autohaus Huber") String tenantName )
    throws IOException {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    this.userRole = userRole;
    this.testType = testType;
    this.tenantName = tenantName;
    this.areaOfBusiness = areaOfBusiness;


    logger.atInfo().log("{}-BaseTest Setup", areaOfBusiness);
    ConfigurationManager.loadProperties(profile);
    driver = getOrCreateWebDriver(browserName, userRole, testType, areaOfBusiness);

    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    this.longWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(300));

    // Instantiate page objects
    this.basePage = new BasePage(driver);

    if (BMW.equals(areaOfBusiness) && !"authentication".equals(testType)) {
        basePage.selectTenant(tenantName);
    }
    logger.info("Tenant name is {}", tenantName);
}

public WebDriver createBrowserSession(String browser, String userRole, String testType,
                                      AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness)
    throws IOException {
    WebDriver webDriver = switch (Browser.fromString(browser)) {
        case FIREFOX -> {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            yield new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        case EDGE -> {
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            yield new EdgeDriver();
        }
        case CHROME -> {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            yield new ChromeDriver();
        }
        case SAFARI -> {
            WebDriverManager.safaridriver().setup();
            yield new SafariDriver();
        }
        case UNKNOWN -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Browser is unknown");
        }
    };
    //wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    longWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(300));
    webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    String backOfficeBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.getBackOfficeBaseUrl();
    webDriver.get(MessageFormat.format(backOfficeBaseUrl,
        AreaOfBusiness.fromString(String.valueOf(areaOfBusiness))));
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Login process
    if (!"authentication".equals(testType)) {
        loginProcess(userRole, AreaOfBusiness.fromString(String.valueOf(areaOfBusiness)), webDriver);
    }
    return webDriver;
}

@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        logger.info("TearDown Called!");
        logger.info("Browser Closed.");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Now when I run the test suite after completion of the first test class in the  tag all these fields become `null` and I am getting `NullPointerException`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="DE BMW-Autohaus Tests on Chrome browser" verbose="1">
    <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
    <parameter name="areaOfBusiness" value="BMW"/>
    <parameter name="tenantName" value="Autohaus Huber"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.myCom.selenium.util.Reporting"/>
        <listener class-name="com.myCom.selenium.util.RetryListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Autohaus Huber Authentication Validation, Login and Logout Tests (Chrome)" enabled="false">
        <parameter name="testType" value="authentication"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.myCom.selenium.testcases.logintests.LoginAndLogoutFunctionalityTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Autohaus Huber Process Owner (Administrator) User Tests (Chrome)" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="userRole" value="process_owner"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="process_owner"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.myCom.selenium.testcases.*">
                <exclude name="com.myCom.selenium.testcases.chat"/>
            </package>
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="Autohaus Huber Service Advisor User Tests (Chrome)" enabled="true" >
        <parameter name="userRole" value="service"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="service_advisor" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.myCom.selenium.testcases.*">
                <exclude name="com.myCom.selenium.testcases.chat"/>
            </package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong for reference let me give you a pageClass and testClass

```
   @Test(groups = {PROCESS_OWNER, SERVICE_ADVISOR, SERVICE_ASSISTANT})
public class FieldsValidationTest extends BaseTestClass {
    private InvoiceCreationPage invoiceCreation;
    private ValidationErrorPage validationErrorPage;
    private CreationDialogUtils creationDialogUtils;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeTest() {
        invoiceCreation = new InvoiceCreationPage(driver);
        validationErrorPage = new ValidationErrorPage(driver);
        creationDialogUtils = new CreationDialogUtils();
    }

    @Test(description = "To test if the user does not check any of the title checks box and verify validation message"
            + "must be displayed")
    public void tc019NewCaseFieldTitleValidationTest() throws Exception {
        creationDialogUtils.openInvoiceCreationDialogBox();
        //Invoice creation form
        //Customer data
        var customerData = randomCustomerData();
        customerData.setTitleIndexValue(4);
        creationDialogUtils.fillCustomerData(invoiceCreation, customerData);
        //Invoice data
        var invoiceData = invoiceData();
        creationDialogUtils.fillInvoiceDetails(invoiceCreation, invoiceData, CREATE, INVOICE_CREATION);
        //Click send invoice button
        invoiceCreation.clickSendButton();
        //Verify validation error message
        var errorMessageData = validationErrors(getErrorMessage("requiredError",
                "Title"));
        checkValidationErrors(validationErrorPage, errorMessageData, "title");
        //Close the form
        invoiceCreation.clickCancelButton();
    }
@Test()
.....
@Test()
.
.
.
@Test() so on 

}
```

Below is the page object class

```
public class InvoiceCreationPage extends BaseTestClass {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvoiceCreationPage.class);

    public InvoiceCreationPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(@href, './invoices')]")
    WebElement invoiceModuleNavLink;
    @FindBy(id = "loader")
    WebElement uploadSpinner;

// Some Action methods
method1();
method2();
.
.
.
.
}
```

If someone helps me, how can I use all the `static` fields as `protected` and also it will be executable in parallel?

I also want to achieve that every `<test>` tag (including all the test classes in `<test>` tag) runs on the same browser and the next `<test>` tag on its individual browser but in parallel